# How can I thicken heavy cream without changing the flavor?

Tags: cream

I am trying to make a thickened heavy cream that would be the same texture as "Creme Fraiche", but have not yet come to a desirable solution. As you guys know Creme Fraiche has a tangy taste similar to Sour Cream which is not what I am looking for. Please advise how I can make thickened heavy cream (not whipped cream) either with any available cultures in the market or individual experiences. Thanks everyone.

Comment: There are simple ways to make Creme fraiche at home (just google it)

Comment: @Max he does not want the flavor of Creme fraiche

Comment: your right about that ( i thought it was only the sour cream taste0

Comment: If you live in Europe, you can try looking for "double cream" which might suit your needs. If not, @Max's answer suggesting Mascarpone would absolutely get you the results you're looking for.

Comment: @SomeInterwebDev double cream is equivalent to US 'heavy cream'

Comment: @canardgras US heavy cream is about 35% fat while double cream is about 48% fat. Might be a little thin but they're certainly not equivalent

Comment: Changing texture always changes the flavor :)

Answer (score 8):

There are several ways to thicken without turning it into whipped cream or imparting other flavors:

- Boil until reduced to desired thickness (whisk constantly, do not burn which will cause the flavor to change)
- Add and incorporate gelatin
- Add and incorporate corn starch or flour

Your desired thickness will dictate how long you boil or how much you incorporate.

Comment: Thanks Caleb. I will try to use the gelatin first and see the result.

Comment: Boiling or heating milk or cream will change the flavour, even if it doesn't burn at all. For that reason I would go with the gelatin option

Answer (score 5):

I was thinking about that yesterday.

You could mix the cream with a little bit of Mascarpone or any other "Fresh" cheese (like Faisselle)

Comment: Absolutely this. Good call.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making clotted cream.  There are a couple of different techniques.

Alton Brown uses a coffee filter to remove some of the water from the cream in [his recipe](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/clotted-cream-1-2103333).  I haven't tried it, but I think it would preserve the flavor of the cream better than recipes that involve cooking.

A more traditional approach is to bake milk or cream until it thickens.  See examples [here](http://www.joyofbaking.com/DevonshireCream.html) and [here](https://fearlessfresh.com/how-to-make-clotted-cream/).